# Create a good looking url for a key with ancestors

Tags: python, google-app-engine, key, google-cloud-datastore

I need to get an instance from a key from ndb. The key may have a parent key, but I don't want to pass any parent keys to the url, because I want a nice looking url.
I don't want to pass the entire key string to the url either.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible. But parent key will be static in your code.

When you get numeric id, you just reconstruct key.

```
id = long(inputId) 
key = ndb.Key('Somekind', 'somevalue', 'kindOfInstance', id)

instance = key.get() # get instance
```

'Somekind' is name of parent class. 'somevalue' is string id of parent class. 'kindOfInstance' is name of instance class. You may use just class without quotes.

Comment: You may also want to look at this: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#allocate_ids so you can reserve some "nice" ids using "allocate_ids (model, count)"

Comment: The parent id is unknown. All information there is is the id of the key of the instance itself and its class.

Comment: @Trollhammaren You may use any parent id or any string. It's just must be same for one entity group. But variant of Paul is better.