# datastore.Get using a grandparent key

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Is there some way to perform a `datastore.Get` by providing not the full path of the key, but, say, the root parent of an entity?

For instance, say there's a `SubFolder` entity, under a `Folder` entity which itself is under a `User` entity. This doesn't work:

```
subFolderKey := datastore.NewKey(c, "SubFolder", "mySubfolder", 0, userKey)
datastore.Get(c, subFolderKey, subFolder)
```

even though `mySubfolder` is a grandchild of `userKey`.

Is there some way to do this without specifying full parent path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. The ancestor path is the full key of your entity so if you leave something out, you will have an incomplete key.

See also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14302641/2021517).

Comment: Thank you. Not sure why I didn't come across that SO question earlier.